# Unable to run friendlyhello tutorial in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to follow some tutorial in docker but sadly I stop in this situation. I followed step by step of this tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#share-your-image. Now, when I try to run the command 
 docker run -d -p 4000:80 friendlyhello I got this error :

```
   docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gracious_poitras
> (791d1921b5d01b6e476c748de76c43ec3f92cd2bcd8069f4e36982f2b2e61759):
> Error starting userland proxy: mkdir
> /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:4000:tcp:172.17.0.2:80: input/output error
```

I am really new in docker and doesn't have any ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: Any information about the `friendlyhello` image?

Comment: did you change anything on app.py file.
ex:- app.run(host=‘0.0.0.0’, port=80) to
app.run(host=‘localhost=80).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573) on GitHub, particularly [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573#issuecomment-301513210). It appears that restarting the Docker daemon (and potentially upgrading) is fixing the issue for most people.

You can do this by running:
`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` to stop all running Docker containers, then restarting Docker on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

- Stop all the running containers `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` then
- Stop the Docker on your machine & `restart` it.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10, `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` is not working. I did following steps.

1. get list of containers by calling `docker ps -a -q`
2. append containers list with stop query `docker stop 0ab2490f8d9c 9dff282e510e 99f64a57b68f b0e9e4d273b1`
3. `restart` docker from task tray.